# Get random table rows whose column weight sum up to a value

Tags: mysql, subset-sum

I have a mysql table like this with about 100 rows

```
id |  text  | weight
---------------------
 1 | textA  |  2
 2 | textB  |  3
 3 | textC  |  8
      ...
```

and I am trying to create a query that would return a random set of rows (but at least 3) of this table, whose sum of weight would be equal to 10. So as a result I would get a number of rows X that sum up to 10.

Could you suggest a way to achieve this? Would it be some sort of plsql script or what?
Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't sound feasible in SQL. I think it would have to be done in application code or a stored procedure.

Comment: A language with arrays makes it much easier. You fetch everything into an array, and then loop over the array looking for rows that sum to your desired value. You can find questions that answer how to do that in a variety of languages.

Comment: I thought of doing this using let's say php, but I was wondering if there is a more efficient way. What about stored procedure you suggested? Can you make any suggestions on that?

Comment: "*a random set of rows (but at least 3) of this table, whose sum of weight would be equal to 10*"—random, at least 3, total weight... those three criteria are mutually exclusive: if you select a given "total weight", then the choices cannot be (totally) "random".  If you select "at least 3", then the "total weight" might necessarily be greater than your desired target (e.g. there's no 3-set in your example above that has a total weight of 10).  Etc.  Sounds like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) to me: what is the actual business problem that you're trying to solve here?

Comment: Not sure how to do it with a stored procedure, since there are no arrays.

Comment: @eggyal Presumably by "random" he means that if there are multiple sets of rows to chooose from that meet the criteria, the choice is not predictable.

Comment: @eggyal what Barmar said is true. My example is a demo data table. Image that I have about 100 rows which in different subset sum up to 10. In these terms, I don't care which of these sets will be returned, as far as their total weight is 10.

Comment: @Omen You need some language that allows you to go through the results repeatedly, calculating sums of different sets of rows. In a MySQL stored procedure you can create a cursor that allows you to loop through the query results, but as far as I can tell there's no way to rewind it. So you would have to keep repeating the query that returns all the rows.

Comment: @Barmar so do you suggest to manipulate the data in a brute force manner let's say in php and make multiple queries to fill in my returning array?

Comment: I suggest you just return all the data to PHP, put it in an array there, and then manipulate the data there in a brute force manner.